# Automatic differentiation via ADOL-C and the Heaviside Function

Tags: c++, automatic-differentiation

I am writting a c++ program in which I define a function $$\displaystyle F(t) = \sum_{i}r_i\,H(t-t_i)$$ where $H$ is the heaviside function, $t_i$ are optimal parameters which are mutable.

The program is derived by automatic differentiation using ADOL-C. 
I am wondering whether I should be careful when I am implementing the function $f$ regarding branching and looping.

I would create the function:

```
template <class Tdouble> Tdouble myfunF ( Tdouble t, Tdouble *tis, int nbti)
{
  Tdouble res = 0.; 
  double ri = 0.; 
  for(int id=0;i<nbti;++i)
  {
    ri = ...;  
    if (t>ti){ 
      res = res + ri; 
    }   
  }
  return res ;
}
```

The *Tdouble* type is similar to the *adouble* type in ADOL-C.
How to analyze if this construction is suitable for automatic differentiation using ADOL-C and rewrite the code ?

Comment: yikesabee. Does any automatic differentiation package handle distributional derivatives correctly? (Only useful under an integral, right?) IIRC, Griewank only discusses non-differentiable functions like abs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used "condassign(a,b,c,d)" for branching in ADOL-C